# How to generate H2 embedded database during Mockito unit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, h2

I'm currently working on a springboot API where it has been decided that me and my coworkers will be using an H2 embedded database during development.

The database is generating itself fine upon starting the application, but I can't make it work during unit test : they all fail saying `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table '[...]' not found`.

I basically did not write most of this code, please let me know if you need more :

`application.properties` file where the H2 database is initialized :

```
datasources.member-request.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DMDEOWNER\\;SET SCHEMA DMDEOWNER\\;runscript from 'classpath:h2_init_script.sql'
datasources.member-request.username=sa
datasources.member-request.password=
datasources.member-request.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
datasources.member-request.initialize=true
```

As you can see above, we execute a SQL script at the initialisation of H2 called `h2_init_script.sql`, in this file we have some SQL statement like this (I'll show you the T_THEME table for example)

```sql
/* CREATE statements */
CREATE TABLE DMDEOWNER.T_THEME (
    F_NUM_THEME NUMBER(14) NOT NULL,
    F_REF_THEME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    F_LIB_THEME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    F_POS_THEME NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    F_BOOL_ACTIF NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    F_UTILISATEUR_MAJ VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    F_DT_CREATION DATE NOT NULL,
    F_DT_MAJ DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (F_NUM_THEME)
);

/* INSERT statements */
/* ... */
```

Here is my test class (and its parent) :

```java
public class ThemeRepositoryTest extends AbstractRepositoryTest {

  private final static int NB_ACTIVE_ENTITIES = 2;
  private final static int NB_INACTIVE_ENTITIES = 1;

  @Autowired
  private ThemeRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  private ThemeMapper mapper;


  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // CREATE
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Before
  public void init() {
    for (int i = INTEGER_ZERO; i < NB_ACTIVE_ENTITIES; i++) {
      insertTheme(true);
    }
    for (int i = INTEGER_ZERO; i < NB_INACTIVE_ENTITIES; i++) {
      insertTheme(false);
    }
    entityManager.flush();
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // READ
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Test
  public void findAll() {
    List<ThemeEntity> list = repository.findAll();
    assertEquals(NB_ACTIVE_ENTITIES + NB_INACTIVE_ENTITIES, list.size());
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public abstract class AbstractRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  protected TestEntityManager entityManager;

  protected ThemeEntity insertTheme(boolean active) {
    ThemeEntity entity =  newThemeEntity(3L, "NAME", active, "USER");
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
  }
}
```

Here is where my error happens, in the `init()` function when I call `insertTheme()` :

```
findAll(io.lacipav.repository.ThemeRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.227 s  <<< ERROR!
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at io.lacipav.repository.ThemeRepositoryTest.init(ThemeRepositoryTest.java:38)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at io.lacipav.repository.ThemeRepositoryTest.init(ThemeRepositoryTest.java:38)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
Table "T_THEME" not found; SQL statement:
select themeentit0_.f_num_theme as f_num_th1_11_0_, themeentit0_.f_bool_actif as f_bool_a2_11_0_, themeentit0_.f_dt_creation as f_dt_cre3_11_0_, themeentit0_.f_dt_maj as f_dt_maj4_11_0_, themeentit0_.f_lib_theme as f_lib_th5_11_0_, themeentit0_.f_pos_theme as f_pos_th6_11_0_, themeentit0_.f_ref_theme as f_ref_th7_11_0_, themeentit0_.f_utilisateur_maj as f_utilis8_11_0_ from t_theme themeentit0_ where themeentit0_.f_num_theme=? [42102-197]
    at io.lacipav.repository.ThemeRepositoryTest.init(ThemeRepositoryTest.java:38)
```

Since the error is telling me that it did not find my table, I'm guessing it is because my database isn't running when I'm building my `.war` file, if so how can I initialize it quicker ?

EDIT : 
As asked for, here's the Entity class for T_THEME :

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "T_THEME")
public class ThemeEntity {

  /** Primary key of the table. */
  @Id
  @NotNull
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "theme_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "theme_generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_NUM_THEME", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "f_num_theme")
  private Long idTechnique;

  /** Theme functional identifier */
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "f_ref_theme")
  private String reference;

  /** Theme simple short length label */
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "f_lib_theme")
  private String name;

  //...
}
```

NOTE : The SQL sequence "SEQ_NUM_THEME" is generated and associated to F_NUM_THEME in the SQL script.

EDIT 2 :

As Lesiak pointed out, my error might be coming from my DataSource being replace by the annotation `@DataJpaTest`. By carefully watching the logs, I found some interesting lines.

```
[INFO ] 2019-05-24 16:22:20.341 [main] org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor.process(TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration.java:106) : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
[INFO ] 2019-05-24 16:22:20.346 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:824) : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
[INFO ] 2019-05-24 16:22:21.050 [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.initDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:189) : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:4ef27020-c472-4be9-a9af-73f5e0175846;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

We can see on the last line that my url connection `jdbc:h2:mem:db` has been replaced by `jdbc:h2:mem:4ef27020-c472-4be9-a9af-73f5e0175846`. This might be why I'm getting some `Table not found` errors.

Comment: Please show us `ThemeEntity` (just `@Entity` annotation)

Comment: Does `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=DMDEOWNER` help?

Comment: Oh yes actually, it still won't work but the error message now says `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "DMDEOWNER" not found;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up trying so much things that I'm not quite sure why it is working now...

In [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support), it is said that by default it will try to find `schema.sql` to create the database and `data.sql` to populate it. I was using my own `.sql` file that did both jobs, so I separated it as recommended and it started to work !

So now my application.properties is as follow :

```
# Datasource connection settings to H2 in-memory database
# To init db with h2_init_script.sql add the following to the url : INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DMDEOWNER\\;SET SCHEMA DMDEOWNER\\;runscript from 'classpath:h2_init_script.sql'
datasources.member-request.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;IGNORECASE=TRUE;
datasources.member-request.username=sa
datasources.member-request.password=
datasources.member-request.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
datasources.member-request.initialize=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Since I'm not creating the schema in the `application.properties` anymore, I added it to the `schema.sql` file :

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DMDEOWNER;
SET SCHEMA DMDEOWNER;
```

Finally, I added the schema's name prefix to my sequence declaration in the Entity classes because I had some `SEQUENCE NOT FOUND` errors :

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "T_THEME")
public class ThemeEntity {

  /** Primary key of the table. */
  @Id
  @NotNull
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "theme_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "theme_generator", sequenceName = "DMDEOWNER.SEQ_NUM_THEME", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "f_num_theme")
  private Long idTechnique;

  //...
}
```

Comment: It is working as you are not using `schema.sql` at all. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html: `In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.`

Comment: Mmmh, that's strange : when I replace `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` by `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` it brings back the `Table "[...]" not found` errors... I'm gonna go backwards and remove stuff bit by bit to see exactly what is needed and not, I'll edit the answer accordingly

Comment: My guess is that you create table with schema in schema.sql, while hibernate ddl  created it within default schema.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `@DataJpaTest` you are using.
See the [Documentation of `@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html)

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest will use an embedded in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured DataSource). The @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation can be used to override these settings.

You will find something similar in the log

```
EmbeddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
```

To fix, use:

```
spring.test.database.replace=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=DMDEOWNER
```

Comment: I've edited the question once more, you're right about that `Replacing 'dataSource' ...` but I'm still having the error saying that the schema `DMDEOWNER` isn't found

Comment: Strange, when I use `spring.test.database.replace=none` this line disappears. Try to set a breakpoint in `EmbeddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor.process` when running your test